# viewpager adapter null when activity recreated

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

I am implementing android application which contains viewpager. the problem is when application is killed in background I have null pointer on the line when I set my viewpager with adapter instance inside asynctask onPostExecute method. below is my code. hope to be helped :)

Snippet inside fragment class where crash happens

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CategoryChild> result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (this.fragmentWeakRef.get() != null) {

                if (result != null) {
                    mHomeCategories = result;

                    if(mBannerViewPager != null){
                    mBannerViewPager.setAdapter(new BannerViewpagerAdapter(
                            getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity()
                                    .getApplicationContext())); // here app crashes after being  killed in background
                                            //  and restored 

                    }
                    mcategoryViewPager.setAdapter(new CategoryViewpagerAdapter(
                            getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity()
                                    .getApplicationContext(),setFragmentsArray()));

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my adapter

```
public class BannerViewpagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private SparseArray<BannerFragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<BannerFragment>();
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> myHashmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    static {
        myHashmap.put(0, R.drawable.img);
        myHashmap.put(1, R.drawable.stopex);
    }

    public BannerViewpagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BannerFragment myFragment = null;

        myFragment = registeredFragments.get(position);

            if(myFragment ==  null){
                myFragment = BannerFragment.newInstance(myHashmap.get(position));
                registeredFragments.put(position, myFragment);
            }


        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.instantiateItem(arg0, arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is logical. Activity is killed, its members are killed too. So, it you should resolve behaviour of you application in such case. You can also add a verifying that your ViewPager exists, like you did some lines above:

```
if (mcategoryViewPager != null) {
        mcategoryViewPager.setAdapter(new CategoryViewpagerAdapter(
                getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity()
                      .getApplicationContext(),setFragmentsArray()))
}
```

Oh. You activity is killed, so getActivity() will return you null. So, just add somewhere before:

```
if (getActivity() == null) { return; }
```

Comment: app crashes at this line mBannerViewPager.setAdapter(newBannerViewpagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

Comment: You are right my friend getactivity() is null. you really heplped me thanks :)